# Math not calculating right in Java

Tags: java

I'm having a bit of trouble here. I'm making a math program that asks the user for the number of digits to use in the math questions. It then asks for the type of math problem, and asks the user 10 questions. It checks to see if the answer is right and displays an appropriate message. If wrong, the user can retry the question forever. It then calculates if they scored over 75% and displays a message.

All of the popups work just fine, but for whatever reason it keeps telling me that the answer is wrong no matter what I enter. I tried to make sure all of the variable types matched up (doubles) so that there wouldn't be any conversion issues with the response, but I'm new to Java so I have no idea if I did that correctly.

Is there any chance you guys can spot the issue with my code? 
Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks for viewing.

Also thanks to those of you who have already helped me with other issues in this project, I'm still learning Java!

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
/**
 *
 */

/**
 * @author Tyler
 *
 */
public class Program {

        /**
         * @param args
         */
        public static void main(String[] args) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
                int difficulty = 1;
                String[] operators = {"plus", "minus", "times", "divided by"};
                int selectedOperator = 1;
                int correctAnswers = 0;
                int answeredTyped = 0;

                int difficultyInput = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please choose the difficulty. Enter the number of digits to use in each problem."));

if (difficultyInput > 0) {
        difficulty = difficultyInput;
}
int arithmeticMethod = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Choose an arithmetic problem to study: 1 = Addition Only, 2 = Subtraction Only, 3 = Multiplication Only, 4 = Division Only, 5 = Random Problems" ));

        selectedOperator = arithmeticMethod;

        new Program().askQuestion(difficulty, null, arithmeticMethod, arithmeticMethod, operators, arithmeticMethod); }





        public static boolean checkResponse (double primaryInt, double secondaryInt, String operatorText, double response){
              if (operatorText.equals("1")){
                  return (primaryInt + secondaryInt) == response;
              }
              else if (operatorText.equals("2")){
                  return (primaryInt - secondaryInt) == response;
              }
              else if (operatorText.equals("3")){
                  return (primaryInt * secondaryInt) == response;
              }
              else if (operatorText.equals("4")){
                  return (primaryInt / secondaryInt) == response;
              }
              return false;
        }




        public static String displayResponse (boolean isCorrect){
        int randomIndex = (int) (Math.floor(Math.random() * (4 - 1 + 1)) + 1);
        switch (randomIndex){
        case 1:
                return isCorrect ? "Very Good!" : "No. Please try again.";
        case 2:
                return isCorrect ? "Excellent!" : "Wrong. Try once more.";
        case 3:
                return isCorrect ? "Nice Work!" : "Don\'t give up!";
        case 4:
                return isCorrect ? "Keep up the good work!" : "No. Keep trying.";
        }
        return "Oops...";
}




        public static void askQuestion(int difficulty, String operatorText, int selectedOperator, int answeredTyped, String[] operators, int correctAnswers){
                boolean correctAnswer = false;
                double primaryInt = Math.floor(Math.pow(10,  difficulty-1) + Math.random() * 9 * Math.pow(10,  difficulty-1));
                double secondaryInt = Math.floor(Math.pow(10,  difficulty-1) + Math.random() * 9 * Math.pow(10, difficulty-1));
                operatorText = (selectedOperator == 5) ? operators[(int) Math.floor(Math.random() * operators.length)] : operators[selectedOperator - 1];

                while(!correctAnswer && answeredTyped < 10) {
                        double response = Double.parseDouble (JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How much is " + primaryInt + " " + operatorText + " " + secondaryInt + "?"));
                        correctAnswer = checkResponse (primaryInt, secondaryInt, operatorText, response);
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, displayResponse(correctAnswer));

                        answeredTyped++;

                        if(correctAnswer)
                                correctAnswers++;
                }

        {

        while(answeredTyped < 10){
                askQuestion(0, null, 0, 0, null, 0);

        }

        if((correctAnswers / answeredTyped) >= 0.75) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Congratulations, you are ready to go on to the next level!");
        }
        else{
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please ask your teacher for extra help.");
        }
}
}
}
```

Comment: correctAnswers and answeredType are both integers. If you do an integer division, the result is an integer too. You have to cast at least one to double or float to get floating point division.

Comment: @isnot2bad, thanks for the suggestion. I hadn't gotten to the actual percentage check yet so I hadn't noticed it. Just trying to get the actual math problems to calculate correctly for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran your program through eclipse debugger and the problem is in the checkResponse method. The operatorText String is populated from your array {"plus", "minus", "times", "divided by"} but you are checking for operatorText.equals("1") etc. This means that none of your check response method is ever actually being run and the method will always just fall through to returning false which explains the behaviour you are experiencing. Change it to operatorText.equals("plus") and you should be good to go.

Tip: Using an IDE like Eclipse and setting up some breakpoints makes it really easy to troubleshoot this kind of issue.

Comment: Thank you so much! I am very new to programming so I haven't really done a whole lot with debugging. Gonna look up some tutorials on using breakpoints to debug tonight.

Answer (score 3):

You're doing `integer` division which results in an `integer`, not a `float` or `double` value. For example:

```
int a = 5;
int b = 2;
System.out.println(a / b); // will print 2
System.out.println((double)a / b); // will print 2.5
```

Comment: This is what I originally thought, but where exactly is it doing that? I thought I changed them all to doubles. I know my variable names say Int, but that's just because they were originally Integers and I hadn't changed them yet (sorry for the bad naming)

Comment: It happens in the last if statement of your code. It's ok if a counter is int - no use for double here. But when you then need to calculate a ratio or anything similar you should cast it to double.

Comment: Yeah, but that's only after calculating the results from 10 questions. I'm actually having issues with the program telling me the answer to the math is incorrect. For instance, it will ask "What is 6.0 + 5.0?" and if I enter 11 (or 11.0), it tells me it's incorrect. 

I'll change the percentage calculation at the end to fix that, but I'm more trying to figure out why it's saying my math is wrong. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried throwing an exception when checkResponse fails to find an operator? I don't see why an invalid operater input should have the same result as getting a question wrong.

If you had that, I'd expect you'd see that none of the if statements in that function resolve to true...why are you comparing to "1", "2", "3", and "4", when that isn't how you defined your operator text?

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. Consider leaving a comment instead.

Comment: I completely didn't think about this. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: I can't leave comments, so that isn't an option. Also, how does this not answer the question?

Answer (score 0):

```
if(((float)correctAnswers / answeredTyped) >= 0.75)
```

Comment: The cast is misplaced.

Comment: @DonRoby: Thanks, I was half-asleep.

Comment: You should address how the OP is doing it wrong instead of just dropping a block of code.

Comment: @ColeJohnson: Thanks mate. Will follow it:)

Answer (score 0):

I put this code into Eclipse and it throws me 8 red flags and 5 yellow. Most of the red flags have to do with the methods 'pow' and 'random' being undefined for 'Math'. Could you be trying to call something that you haven't actually written?

```
        double primaryInt = Math.floor(Math.pow(10, difficulty - 1)
            + Math.random() * 9 * Math.pow(10, difficulty - 1));
    double secondaryInt = Math.floor(Math.pow(10, difficulty - 1)
            + Math.random() * 9 * Math.pow(10, difficulty - 1));
    operatorText = (selectedOperator == 5) ? operators[(int) Math
            .floor(Math.random() * operators.length)]
            : operators[selectedOperator - 1];
```

This could possibly be fixed by changing your class name to something other than a standard 'Math' if you are actually trying to call the java Math methods.

Comment: If this is the issue, he should be getting an error himself, right?

Comment: Ah I didn't even think about that. I have the class actually named something else, I just changed it to the generic "Math" to post here. Never thought about it interacting badly with that.

Comment: I actually went ahead and edited the code in the OP to make it class "Program" so that shouldn't be an issue anymore.